# Alternatives of global variable in c

Tags: c, scope, global-variables, storage-class-specifier

Is Static variable is an alternative to global variable?
If it is no.Then What is the alternatives of global variables in   C language 
I'm look forward your answers
Thx u for advance

Comment: What is a _static variable_?

Comment: A local variable is an alternative to a global variable. But seriously, what exactly are your requirements for "alternative"?

Comment: Why do you need an alternate to global variables. Having 2 features that serve the same purpose is kind of redundant. Unless you have something more/extra feature that you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing as such called *static variable*, it's a(ny) variable with `static` storage duration.

Global variables ( residing in file scope ) have `static` storage duration, but locally scoped variable can also have `static` storage, they are not mutually exclusive. So, there's no "alternative" as such.

As for variables with `static` storage duration, they retain their values throughout the execution, you may feel that "global" and "static local scope" (is that mean anything) are *"alternatives"*. Well, from the abstraction point of view, if you don't need the variable to be accessed from other translation unit, you have no reason to put it in a file scope.

A locally scoped variable with `static` storage, if serves your purpose, is considered a better approach than having a variable in file scope.